# Why does evince display "BUG" warnings when viewing a certain pdf?

Tags: gnome, pdf, evince

I made a PDF document with `pdftex`.  When I run `evince document.pdf` these warnings always appear:

```
*** BUG ***
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug
```

Similar bug warnings can be seen in *Eclipse* but I'm not sure if that's related.

OS and DE: *Debian 8.5* with *Gnome 3.14*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because someone is a bad programmer. The developer of one of the software layers (either evince itself or one of the many libraries it uses) has either misused a function or programmed a function to emit spurious messages. Somehow it mostly works.

Unfortunately, these messages are extremely common in Gnome software. Just ignore them.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for more stable system or window manager? - - I need stability for my scientific computing hobby.

Comment: @Masi Gnome isn't particularly unstable (apart from compiz).